# Unable to run couchbase container with non standard ports

Tags: docker, go, couchbase

## Update 04/09/20 (jj/mm/aaaa)

I tried running my couchbase instance on custom ports by playing with couchbase configuration files.

```
docker run -d --privileged --memory 3200M --name bumblebase \
-v '$PWD/static_config:/opt/couchbase/etc/couchbase/static_config' \
-p 3456-3461:3456-3461 -p 6575-6576:6575-6576 \
couchbase:community-6.6.0
```

static_config is a file I created with the following content, following [this page instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gwN8.png) (bottom section) :

```
{rest_port, 3456}.
{query_port, 3458}.
{fts_http_port, 3459}.
{cbas_http_port, 3460}.
{eventing_http_port, 3461}.
{memcached_port, 6575}.
```

But then I cannot access my couchbase instance at all (either web UI or rest api). I tried to point my local ports to both custom and default ports (-p 3456-3461:8091-8096) but none worked, and the problem disappear only if I remove the -v option - which brings me back to the original post scenario.

On a side note, I'm still trying to play with [setting-alternate-address](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/cli/cbcli/couchbase-cli-setting-alternate-address.html) without any success so far. For some reason, when I set the alternate hostname (which seems to be required for this to run), accessing the alternate address takes a long time to load to eventually fail with a timeout error.

## Original post

Since I develop many applications running different couchbase clusters, I have to run them in containers on different port. I created my container with the following command :

```
docker run -d --memory 2048M --name "my-database" \
    -p 3456-3461:8091-8096 \
    -p 6210-6211:11210-11211 \
    couchbase
```

I then added buckets, and going on the web UI at localhost:3456 works fine :

[image]

Here is my server info :

[image]

In my code I have the following connect function :

```golang
var cluster *gocb.Cluster

func Cluster() *gocb.Cluster {
    return cluster
}

func init() {]
    c, err := gocb.Connect(
        "couchbase://127.0.0.1:3456",
        gocb.ClusterOptions{
            Username: "Administrator",
            Password: "password",
            TimeoutsConfig: gocb.TimeoutsConfig{
                ConnectTimeout: 30 * time.Second,
            },
        },
    )

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    cluster = c
}
```

Panic doesn't trigger, but whenever I try to perform a KV operation, it fails with the following error :

```
ambiguous timeout | {"InnerError":{"InnerError":{"InnerError":{},"Message":"ambiguous timeout"}},"OperationID":"Add","Opaque":"0x0","TimeObserved":2501547947,"RetryReasons":null,"RetryAttempts":0,"LastDispatchedTo":"","LastDispatchedFrom":"","LastConnectionID":""}
```

And this error only comes when I try to connect to my docker couchbase instance. If I run the Couchbase Server application and connect to appropriate port (8091), it works perfectly fine :

```golang
var cluster *gocb.Cluster

func Cluster() *gocb.Cluster {
    return cluster
}

func init() {]
    c, err := gocb.Connect(
        "couchbase://localhost",
        gocb.ClusterOptions{
            Username: "Administrator",
            Password: "password",
            TimeoutsConfig: gocb.TimeoutsConfig{
                ConnectTimeout: 30 * time.Second,
            },
        },
    )

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    cluster = c
}
```

I checked the credentials and they are correct, also replacing localhost with 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1 didn't help at all.

Comment: Have you configured [alternate addresses](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/clusters-and-availability/connectivity.html#alternate-addresses) so the Couchbase Server advertises the external/mapped docker host and port instead of the defaults?

Comment: @dnault made an update to the post based on your suggestion. I seem to make some progress but unfortunately I'm still getting stuck :/